# Glitch when moving sprite with moveTo function on pointer down

Tags: phaser-framework

I'm trying to move a sprite based on the user click/touch event position.

Here is a demo of what I have done so far:
https://codepen.io/louiscuny/pen/GeQQbZ

```js
var pointer
var logo

function create ()
{
    logo = this.physics.add.image(400, 100, 'ball');
    pointer = this.input.activePointer
}

function update() {
  logo.setVelocity(0)
  if (pointer.isDown) {
    this.physics.moveTo(logo, pointer.worldX, pointer.worldY, 600)
  }
}
```

It's working as expected but there is a glitch when the sprite is under the pointer.

I tried to mitigate this behaviour by using Math.floor on coordinates or to not call the moveTo method when distance between pointer and sprite is too low but nothing seems to work.

Point me in the right direction please :)

Answer (score 0):

After some trials and errors I finally found the right threshold.

```
if (Phaser.Math.Distance.Between(logo.x, logo.y, pointer.worldX, pointer.worldY) > 5)
  this.physics.moveTo(logo, pointer.worldX, pointer.worldY, 600)
```

https://codepen.io/louiscuny/pen/rRKYwJ